# how can I take values out of many strings

Tags: r, string

I have a data like below

```
df<-structure(list(X__1 = c("Q6NVC0 [197-213]", "A0A0A8UAS1 [48-64]", 
"A0A0F0XK65 [8-17]", "A0A0G2JMX7 [481-491]; P20406-6 [106-116]; Q6UIN5 [7-17]; P20406-3 [70-80]; P20406-8 [164-174]", 
"A0A0G2JMX7 [481-497]; P20406-6 [106-122]; Q6UIN5 [7-23]; P20406-3 [70-86]; P20406-8 [164-180]", 
"P20406-6 [106-132]; Q6UIN5 [7-33]; P20406-3 [70-96]; P20406-8 [164-190]", 
"H6VRG2 [603-616]", "P13645 [41-59]", "P35527 [488-513]", "P35908 [525-544]; H2R1Z0 [512-531]", 
"H6VRG2 [550-588]", "A0A024RBS2 [150-162]", "A0A023L3M5 [83-110]", 
"P10809 [143-156]", "V9HW22 [470-493]", "P20406-8 [379-392]", 
"P19338 [524-537]", "A0A024L4P7 [46-57]", "G7YYH5 [45-55]", "Q86YZ3 [973-991]; [1443-1461]; [1913-1931]; [2383-2401]", 
"P35527 [375-390]", "P35527 [375-391]", "D2TTS3 [41-50]")), .Names = "X__1", class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

I am trying to make an output like this 
At first I try to get the value next to one two IDs P20406-8 and A0A024RBS2. If they dont exist in a row, we take the first two values of any other ID. if they exist together, we take the value next to the first one and if one of the ID is there, we take its value.

So at the end I want a two column of values like below

```
197 213
48  64
8   17
164 174
164 180
164 190
603 616
41  59
488 513
525 544
550 588
150 162
83  110
143 156
470 493
379 392
524 537
46  57
45  55
973 991
375 390
375 391
41  50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works just fine for me:

```
df_new <- df2$X__1
primary_ID <- "P20406-8"
secondary_ID <- "A0A024RBS2"

ID_Primary <- grepl(pattern = primary_ID, df_new)
ID_Secondary <- grepl(pattern = secondary_ID, df_new)

df_new[ID_Primary] <- substr(df_new[ID_Primary],
                              start = regexpr(primary_ID, df_new[ID_Primary]), 
                              stop = 2000)

df_new[ID_Secondary & !ID_Primary] <- substr(df_new[ID_Secondary],
                                               start = regexpr(secondary_ID, df_new[ID_Secondary]), 
                                               stop = 2000)

start <- regexpr(pattern = "\\[", text = df_new)  # find opening square bracket
end <- regexpr(pattern = "\\]", text = df_new)  # find closing square bracket
temp <- substr(df_new, start+1, end-1)  # only take values between opening and closing
temp <- strsplit(temp, "-")  # split values in two

result <- t(data.frame(temp))
rownames(result) <- NULL
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, this is very good but you don't take into account the ID that I gave. Can you please have a look at the question?

Comment: Updated the code now! Let me know if it works as you expect!

Comment: thank you so much. I will like and accept it, however, I think there is a small bug in there. Look at the df2, you see that it should give the value for `P20406_8`but instead it gives the value for the first string. do you know why?

Comment: I just ran it! It gave me always the numbers next to P20406_8! Result is: 1)11,22 2)341,349 3)341,353 4)191,209 5)191,211
What should the result be?

Comment: now please search `P10636-8` instead `P20406-8`? I don't know why when I change the ID, it gives different output and somewhat confuses . can you please check now df2?

Comment: I edited the code once more, so you can play around with the IDs yourself! :-) I do not see any problem: it always checks for the primary ID and value, then secondary ID and value, then all the rest! 
Please tell specifically what is wrong, otherwise I would consider it solved ;-)

Comment: I am really thankful for your amazing help. I liked and accepted the answer. Please put the ID I gave for df there

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
library(splitstackshape)
# separate multi observation lines into multiple columns
df2 <- cSplit(df, splitCols='X__1', sep=';')
# put in a long format for easier processing
df3 <- na.omit(data.frame(melt(as.data.frame(df2),measure=names(df2))))

# extractions
# account id
df3$id <- with(df3,gsub(x=value,pattern="^(.*) [[:punct:]](.*)-(.*)[[:punct:]]$",replacement='\\1'))
# start range
df3$begin <- with(df3,gsub(x=value,pattern="^(.*) [[:punct:]](.*)-(.*)[[:punct:]]$",replacement='\\2'))
# end range
df3$end <- with(df3,gsub(x=value,pattern="^(.*) [[:punct:]](.*)-(.*)[[:punct:]]$",replacement='\\3'))
# accounts with multiple:
df3$mult_id <- as.numeric(with(df3,gsub(x=variable,pattern="^X__1_(.*)$",replacement='\\1')))


# apparently you only want those with one obs:
df.final <- df3[which(df4$mult_id==1),]
```

Comment: thanks Nate, I cannot download the package you are workin with. I will do it when I am home and check your output. I will like your answer in any case. Thanks again